# Angular2 Call login function from service in component and return error

Tags: http, service, angular, components

I'm trying to call a service HTTP method and eventually return an error message but after a week of trying many things (Promises, Observables, ...) I can't get it to work. I hope anybody can help me out?

I'm kind of new to Angular2 and working alone on this project, with no one else around me with any Angular expertise. I did get a 3-day training course.

Component

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  error: string;

  constructor(private navController: NavController, private auth: AuthService) {
  }

  private login(credentials) {
    // Method calling the login service
    // Could return an error, or nothing
    this.error = this.auth.login(credentials);

    // If there is no error and the user is set, go to other page
    // This check is executed before previous login methode is finished...
    if (!this.error && this.auth.user) {
      this.navController.setRoot(OverviewPage);
    }
  }
}
```

AuthService

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private LOGIN_URL: string = "http://localhost:8080/rest/auth";
  private USER_URL: string = "http://localhost:8080/rest/user";

  private contentHeader: Headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });

  errorMessage: string;
  user: User;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  login(credentials) {
      let contentHeader = new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      });

    this.http.post(this.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: contentHeader })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.handleLogin(data),
        err => this.handleError
      );

    // could return an errorMessage or nothing/null
    return this.errorMessage;
  }

  private handleLogin(data) {
    let token = data.token;
    this.getAccount(token);
  }

  private getAccount(token) {
    let authHeader = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Auth-Token": token
    });

    this.http.get(this.USER_URL, { headers: authHeader })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.setUser(data),
        err => this.errorMessage = err
      );
  }

  private setUser(data) {
    this.user = new User(data.naam, data.voornaam);
  }

  private handleError(error) {
    // this.errorMessage is not saved?

    if (error.status === 401) {
      this.errorMessage = '401';
    } else if (error.status === 404) {
      this.errorMessage = '404';
    } else {
      this.errorMessage = 'Server error';
    }

    return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that your login method is returning a flat value (`errorMessage`).  Since the login method is making an asynchronous request that value will not be initialized, it will always return null.  If I were to set this up I would have the login method return an `Observable`.

Then to make things a bit more complicated it appears you want to make a consecutive call after login to get the logged in user.  If you don't want your login method to emit until you've completed both calls you have to combine them somehow.  I think `switch` can do this.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private LOGIN_URL: string = "http://localhost:8080/rest/auth";
  private USER_URL: string = "http://localhost:8080/rest/user";

  private contentHeader: Headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });

  user: User;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  login(credentials) {
      let contentHeader = new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      });

      let response:Observable<Response> = this.http.post(this.LOGIN_URL, JSON.stringify(credentials), { headers: contentHeader });

      //Take response and turn it into either a JSON object or 
      //a string error.
      //This is an Observable<any> (any is returned by json())
      let jsonResponse = response.map(res => res.json())
                                 .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
      //Take JSON object and turn it into an Observable of whatever the
      //login request returns
      //This is an Observable<Observable<any>> (Observable<any> is returned
      //by handleLogin
      let userResponse = jsonResponse.map(
        data => this.handleLogin(data)
      );

      //Switch to the observable of the login request
      //This is an Observable<any>, we will switch to the Observable<any>
      //returned by handleLogin
      let finalResponse = userResponse.switch();

      //Hide actual response value from user.  This will return an
      //observable that will emit null on success and an error message
      //on error
      //Again, an Observable<any> since we're mapping to null
      return finalResponse.map(res => null);
  }

  //We need to return this call as an observable so we can wire it into
  //our chain
  private handleLogin(data) {
    let token = data.token;
    return this.getAccount(token);
  }

  private getAccount(token) {
    let authHeader = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Auth-Token": token
    });

    let loginResponse = this.http.get(this.USER_URL, { headers: authHeader })
                                 .map(res => res.json())
                                 .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));

      loginResponse.subscribe(
        data => this.setUser(data)
      );

      return loginResponse;
  }

  private setUser(data) {
    this.user = new User(data.naam, data.voornaam);
  }

  private handleError(error) {
    let errorMessage = "Uninitialized";
    if (error.status === 401) {
      errorMessage = '401';
    } else if (error.status === 404) {
      errorMessage = '404';
    } else {
      errorMessage = error.json() || 'Server error';
    }
    return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Now in your login component you will need to listen asynchronously to the response.  This won't happen immediately (probably pretty quick with localhost, but may take a while in the real world) so I've added a loginDisabled that you can use to prevent the user from hitting the login button twice while waiting for the login request to be fulfilled.

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  error: string;
  loginDisabled:boolean = false;

  constructor(private navController: NavController, private auth: AuthService) {
  }

  private login(credentials) {
    // Method calling the login service
    // Could return an error, or nothing
    this.loginDisabled = true;
    this.auth.login(credentials).subscribe(
      rsp => {
        //On success, navigate to overview page
        this.navController.setRoot(OverviewPage);
      }, err => {
        //On failure, display error message
        this.error = err;
        this.loginDisabled = false;
    });

  }
}
```

No promises this is all correct (I don't have anything to test it against) but it should be the right general direction.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer! It is exactly what I was looking for and working like a charm!
And a big thank you for working out the Observables and the comments, it makes it so much more clear for me what exactly is happing.

Small fix for people who want to use the same code:
`Observable<Request>` should be `Observable<Response>`
and
`data => this.handleLogin(data);` should be without ';' `data => this.handleLogin(data)`